# React-native-screens error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTypefaceUtils;

Tags: react-native, react-native-screens

.../node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenStackHeaderConfig.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
**import com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTypefaceUtils;**
^
symbol:   class ReactTypefaceUtils
location: package com.facebook.react.views.text

.../node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenStackHeaderConfig.java:247: error: cannot find symbol
Typeface titleTypeface = ReactTypefaceUtils.applyStyles(
^
symbol:   variable ReactTypefaceUtils
location: class ScreenStackHeaderConfig

.../node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenStackHeaderConfig.java:377: error: cannot find symbol
**mTitleFontWeight = ReactTypefaceUtils.parseFontWeight(fontWeightString);**
^
symbol:   variable ReactTypefaceUtils
location: class ScreenStackHeaderConfig

I am using
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",

Comment: Same issue have you found any solution ?

Comment: @KishanBharda I have fixed these issue by updating gradle using android studio.

Comment: @Xhirazi what version of Gradle did you upgrade to?